# How to add flow in your LWC QuickAction button?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have made a ScreenType action in lightning web component and want to add a flow to when i click yes. I have not found any guide or documentation regarding this. Can you please suggest on how to add flow to my screenType.

```
<template>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header="Confirmation">
        <p class="slds-align_absolute-center">Are you sure to Delete this record?</p>
    
        <div slot="footer">
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="No" onclick={closeModal}>
            </lightning-button>
            &nbsp;
            <lightning-button variant="brand" onclick={handleSubmit} label="Yes">
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class DeleteAnimalRecord extends LightningElement {

 recordId;

 @wire(CurrentPageReference)
 getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
     if (currentPageReference) {
         this.recordId = currentPageReference.state.recordId;
     }
 }

 handleSubmit() {
     console.log('RECORD_ID : ', this.recordId);
 }

 closeModal() {
     this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
 }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
   </targets>
   <targetConfigs>
       <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
           <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
       </targetConfig>
   </targetConfigs>
   </LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Take a look at unofficialsf.com where you will find some components to help you with this. LWC doesn't currently support starting (screen) flows from custom actions.

Comment: yes as @PhilW said LWC not yet support calling flow from LWC, but you can try  wrap your lwc with aura and dispatch event from lwc to aura then call from flow from that action.

Comment: :( Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you create the screentype action using flow and call the flow

the lightning:flow component is commonly inserted into aura components to enable screen flows to run when those components are rendered. What if you want to insert a flow into your own LWC component?If you’re building an LWC, you can’t currently just invoke lightning:flow because it has not yet become available in an LWC version (and LWC doesn’t allow Aura components to be inserted).

To address, that, the ScreenFlow LWC installable from this page provides a way to insert a flow into your own LWC container. Simply invoke it in your LWC

When your component instantiates, it will load the named flow into an iframe created with the specified height and width, and pass in any input params you provide.